# I have to use can or could?

Tags: grammar

I wanted to tell the person that we can ship the package instead of they come to us.

> Could you please help to provide us the address?
>   Our team could ship the package to you.

The first "could" is correct but the second, I'm not sure.

Please advise.

I had read the http://www.yourdictionary.com/could but I couldn't find the same situation.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but this sentence sounds stilted to me. I could instantly tell it's from a non-native speaker. There's a lot of unnecessary words. "Could you please provide the address?" sounds much more natural. "Help to [verb]" is not a common construction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either "can" or "could" in  your example, but "could" is slightly more polite.  Both are indirect ways of making the offer, since it is not literally about ability, and "could" suggests there might hypothetically be conditions that *would* make it difficult for the customer to come to you directly to receive the goods.